# CSS pseudo class :link not supported. Is there any equivalent?

Tags: css, hyperlink, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm new to CSS, and I was wondering, is there another way to write an equivalent to pseudo class :link , in case :link is not supported?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Alink - only IE6 lacks the support, I don't think you need to worry about it nowadays

Comment: `:matches(:any-link:not(:visited))` is equivalent, but has much less browser support.

Comment: @Zoltan Toth: That description is misleading - :link is not a CSS2.1 selector, and IE6 certainly does support it.

Comment: @Oriol: You can't put a :not() in :matches() and vice versa AFAIK. The equivalent is :matches(:any-link):not(:visited), or more simply, :any-link:not(:visited).

Comment: @BoltClock But `:any-link:not(:visited)` has more specificity. Why can't `:not()` be nested in `:matches()`?

Comment: @Oriol: I'm not sure, and it looks like that rule isn't in the latest ED anymore. So I'm not sure what changed. How does it have more specificity?

Comment: @BoltClock Fair enough. I didn't see the specificity of `:matches` in [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches) so I though its specificity was just 1 class. But this is defined in [Calculating a selector’s specificity](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#specificity-rules), and `:matches` has the specificity of its argument, just like `:not`. Neither is completely equivalent, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, in selectors-4 you can write `:any-link:not(:visited)`, but you are going to be hard-pressed to find any browsers that support `:visited` but not `:link`, let alone `:any-link`, browser regressions notwithstanding.

A slightly more widely-supported selector requires knowledge of the document language since the link pseudo-classes themselves match different elements based on document semantics. In HTML, `:link` can be expressed as the following level 3 selector-list:

```
a[href]:not(:visited), area[href]:not(:visited), link[href]:not(:visited)
```

The same caveat applies.

If you're asking about browsers that support *neither* of the link pseudo-classes, remove the `:not(:visited)` from the above selector-list. If you're asking how to match links based on their visitedness in browsers that support neither pseudo-class, then it becomes impossible. But there are no known browsers that lack support for the link pseudo-classes, so this will never be a problem if you're making websites.

---

Note that [CSS1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#anchor-pseudo-classes) and [CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes) define `:link` and `:visited` to apply only to `a` elements — the standalone [Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited) standard (level 3 and up) instead defers to the document language, and in the case of HTML, the current definition above is provided by [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#pseudo-classes). What this means in theory is that browsers up to and including IE6 (not sure about IE7) don't support the link pseudo-classes on elements other than `a[href]`, and that's because IE6 was designed to be CSS1-compliant, not CSS2-compliant.

What this means in practice depends on whether or not you use the link pseudo-classes to match `area` or `link` elements, and whether or not you support browsers dating back to IE7, in the first place. If you're like 99.9% of authors who don't use them with `area` or `link` elements, then this means absolutely nothing to you in practice.

Answer (score 0):

The `a {}` selector (`{}` added since it's so short) will apply to all pseudo classes though `a:link` will override specific styling for URLs the user has not yet visited.

Someone mentioned an exceptionally old version of Internet Explorer. If you're new to CSS you should *first* concentrate on current browsers. If you're learning at this point the oldest version of IE that you'll be supporting is IE11 if working with CSS will become a part of your future career.

Comment: Oh okay I see! But just for the theoretical knowledge though, if pseudo classes aren't supported how would we write the selectors equivalently?

Comment: In CSS the deliminator for selectors is a comma: `a:link, a {color: #aaa;}` for example though anyone advanced enough would remove the `, a` part from the selector.

Comment: Browsers that don't support :link would drop the entire rule anyway - you'll be forced to split the selectors and duplicate the styles across them.